# How do I import Firefox bookmarks, with tags, to Google Bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, google-bookmarks

There are many previous answers to this, but they all seem out-of-date, because of changes to Google's support for various interfaces, for example the dropping of google-toolbar-for-firefox.

Going via delicious might still be an option (it isn't clear to me!), but do we *have* to involve yet-another service, really?

Comment: Delicious import-from-file is currently not working. The site suggests using the delicious API. I could write a tool to do delicious import, which might be easier than writing a tool to do Google Bookmarks import, since AFAICS the later does not expose a documented API! Assuming the Delicious->Bookmarks tool works, of course!

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the Google Bookmarks in the cloud (https://www.google.com/bookmarks/), then I spent quite some time looking for it but couldn't find a solution, so wrote up a Selenium/Firefox tool to do the job. It is crude, but it does the job. You can find the source code here:

https://github.com/kevinxyz/google_bookmarks_importer